# Silex symfony ACL without ORM

Tags: acl, silex

Is there any way to implement ACL using Silex, but without Doctrine ORM?

Using entities we can handle this like this

```
$oidd = new Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($message(\);
$acl = $app['security.acl.provider']->createAcl($oidd);

// the current user is the owner
$sid = Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($currentUser);
$acl->insertObjectAce($sid, Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this example project.

- https://github.com/davedevelopment/silex-acl-demo

The relevant bootstrap code is here (and works for me with Silex 1.2):

- https://github.com/davedevelopment/silex-acl-demo/blob/master/app/bootstrap.php#L59

From the README:

> This is a demo of Symfony's ACL using Silex. I've tried
>   to annotate the services in app/bootstrap.php, but to be honest, I
>   originally reverse engineered the symfony full stack frameworks DI
>   configuration without fully understanding what everything does, still
>   don't!

Comment: The linked project uses Doctrine ORM.